# How to remove space between list items in navigation (HTML / CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble removing the space between the li items in navigation, I already set the margin: 0px for the item & anchor (a link) but the space/gap  still exist.

How can I remove those spaces?

[image]

```css
/* navigation styles */

nav {
  background: rgba(6, 19, 72, 1);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(6, 19, 72, 1) 0%, rgba(15, 31, 91, 1) 100%);
}
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0px;
}
nav ul.nav {
  width: 1120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 120px;
}
span.homeicon {
  width: 35px;
  height: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('http://s16.postimg.org/cq68hbikx/home_icon.png');
  background-size: cover;
}
.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 120px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #344da7;
  border-top: none;
}
a.nav_home {
  max-width: 50px;
  width: 50px !important;
}
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #344da7;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="" class="nav_home"><span class="homeicon"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="">SPORTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="">LIVE CASINO</a></li>
    <li><a href="">SLOTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="">POKER</a></li>
    <li><a href="">PROMOTION</a></li>
    <li><a href="">BANKING</a></li>
    <li><a href="">AFFILIATE</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

## [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ojL3ysc6/1/)

Comment: Your `.nav a` is set to be 120px wide. Removing / changing that will solve the problem.

Comment: Do you have a css reset: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: yes I have css reset @Mikey

Comment: @Billy I tried it, the gap still there

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that you are referring to the gap outside the links (my monitor is too dark to see the border in your screenshot). Will see what caused the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These spaces are actually caused by the white space in your html.

To solve, add `float: left` to your `<li>` tags:

```
.nav li {
    float: left;
}
```

To see that it really is the whitespace in your HTML, try removing it and testing:

```css
.nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px;
}
nav ul.nav {
    width: 1120px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 120px;
}
span.homeicon {
    width: 35px;
    height: 32px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('http://s16.postimg.org/cq68hbikx/home_icon.png');
    background-size: cover;
}
.nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 120px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: arial;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #344da7;
}
a.nav_home {
    max-width: 50px;
    width: 50px !important;
}
.nav a:hover {
    background-color: #344da7;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h1> With Whitespace </h1>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="" class="nav_home"><span class="homeicon"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="">SPORTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="">LIVE CASINO</a></li>
    <li><a href="">SLOTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="">POKER</a></li>
    <li><a href="">PROMOTION</a></li>
    <li><a href="">BANKING</a></li>
    <li><a href="">AFFILIATE</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <h1> Without Whitespace </h1>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="" class="nav_home"><span class="homeicon"></span></a></li><li><a href="">SPORTS</a></li><li><a href="">LIVE CASINO</a></li><li><a href="">SLOTS</a></li><li><a href="">POKER</a></li><li><a href="">PROMOTION</a></li><li><a href="">BANKING</a></li><li><a href="">AFFILIATE</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try looking at https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

You might want to try using `display: flex;` instead https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

The spaces are caused by white spaces. You should make sure that there are no spaces in between each `li`.

The best way to do so IMO:

```
<ul class="nav"><!--
    --><li><a href="" class="nav_home"><span class="homeicon"></span></a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="">SPORTS</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="">LIVE CASINO</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="">SLOTS</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="">POKER</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="">PROMOTION</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="">BANKING</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="">AFFILIATE</a></li>
</ul>
```

Sure, you can change your entire layout to using floats, but that is really not the best way, and kind of going backwards. `inline-block` was created specifically to address the problems with using floats for layout.

Comment: No, I think the best solution is to use flex boxes. What's more, most of the time this stuff is generated by server side php/ruby and so you may as well just not include the whitespace (it's easy enough to beautify in order to debug).

Comment: Sure, flexbox works as well (and is a newer technique). But I'm suggesting the path of least resistance, since the OP's layout is already using inline-block, which is really not wrong at all.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the space between the navigation items, just do this:

```
ul {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Comment: good!.. and "li" with any font-size